# Flutter - Getting initializing audio error when navigating one video to another video

Tags: flutter, video, video-player, flutter-video-player

I have 5-6 videos and set them in slider. all things are working fine during navigation from one video to another but sometimes dart generate below error then video does not play. I am using video_player standard player to run videos. I am getting below error in debug console in visual studio code editor.

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(30180): Release 80d07 [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [mido, Redmi Note 4, Xiaomi, 24] [goog.exo.core]
I/ExoPlayerImpl(30180): Init d652959 [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [mido, Redmi Note 4, Xiaomi, 24]
I/OMXClient(30180): MuxOMX ctor
I/MediaCodec(30180): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 30904353
I/ExtendedACodec(30180): setupVideoDecoder()
I/ExtendedACodec(30180): vpp-enable search is 0 and value is 0
I/ExtendedACodec(30180): Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
D/SurfaceUtils(30180): set up nativeWindow 0x7f5dbedc10 for 640x362, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x2002900
I/OMXClient(30180): MuxOMX ctor
I/ACodec  (30180): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
I/ACodec  (30180): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
D/SurfaceUtils(30180): set up nativeWindow 0x7f5dbedc10 for 640x368, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x2002900
E/AudioTrack(30180): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
E/AudioTrack-JNI(30180): Error -12 initializing AudioTrack
E/android.media.AudioTrack(30180): Error code -20 when initializing AudioTrack.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180): Playback error.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180): com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioSink$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 12, 56576)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioRenderer.java:646)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1355)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:663)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:529)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:300)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180): Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioSink$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 12, 56576)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.initializeAudioTrack(DefaultAudioSink.java:1128)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.initialize(DefaultAudioSink.java:532)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.DefaultAudioSink.handleBuffer(DefaultAudioSink.java:593)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     at com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioRenderer.java:640)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(30180):     ... 7 more
I/ExoPlayerImpl(30180): Release d652959 [ExoPlayerLib/2.9.6] [mido, Redmi Note 4, Xiaomi, 24] [goog.exo.core]
```

I have already spent more than 10 hours to fix this simple issue but did not get success yet.

Kindly suggest me what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem. When you call dispose your controller is still being used by VideoPlayer widget. First, you need to make sure that it's not used anymore (setting controller in state to null) and AFTER that you call dispose.

I'm not sure about your state management via Provider, but I'll give you an example how to do this with regular State.

```
VideoPlayerController _controller;

  void _initController(String link) {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(link)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  Future<void> _onControllerChange(String link) async {
    if (_controller == null) {
      // If there was no controller, just create a new one
      _initController(link);
    } else {
      // If there was a controller, we need to dispose of the old one first
      final oldController = _controller;

      // Registering a callback for the end of next frame
      // to dispose of an old controller
      // (which won't be used anymore after calling setState)
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        await oldController.dispose();

        // Initing new controller
        _initController(link);
      });

      // Making sure that controller is not used by setting it to null
      setState(() {
        _controller = null;
      });
    }
  }
```

This solution worked for me. Thanks.